# Filter products by name "LIKE" on a WC_Product_Query in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In WooCommerce using `wc_get_products()` function I would like to find a way to filter products by **name** using the `LIKE` operator.

Actually I am only able to filter products by a specific defined name with:

```
$args = array(
    'limit' => 5,
    'name' => 'Test',
);
$result = wc_get_products( $args );
```

Is it possible to filter products where the **name is LIKE 'test'**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look to [WooCommerce official documentation for `WC_Product_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#adding-custom-parameter-support) at the end on the section **"Adding Custom Parameter Support"** you will see that you can manipulate the WC_Product_Query with a custom hooked function.

So to filter the query with a product name "LIKE" parameter, you can extend the query with the search "s" argument, that will do the trick as follow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
function handle_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( isset( $query_vars['like_name'] ) && ! empty( $query_vars['like_name'] ) ) {
        $query['s'] = esc_attr( $query_vars['like_name'] );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

---

**USAGE example** with custom argument "like_name":

```
$args = array(
    'limit' => 5,
    'like_name' => 'test',
);

wc_get_products( $args );
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks so much

Comment: Is it possible to extend this code so that it returns products that contains something like when I have a product named `Einfaches Produkt` and I enter `Product` I want to see it as well.

Comment: By default, the `s` parameter is already working on the `wc_get_products()`. In other words. You can already use it like this: `wc_get_products( array( 's' => 'Test' ) )`